# When I am trying to use float values inside of a Text field in React the point or comma gets deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with some text fields and values. The values are already given. They are all whole numbers and I am trying to change one of them to a float using point or comma but when I use the comma or point they get deleted.

```
const DEFAULT_CHARGING_CURVE = [
 { SoC: 44, power: 250 },
 { SoC: 48, power: 240 },
 { SoC: 51, power: 220 },
 { SoC: 54, power: 200 },
 { SoC: 57, power: 180 },
 { SoC: 61, power: 170 },
 { SoC: 65, power: 160 },
 { SoC: 69, power: 155 },
 { SoC: 70, power: 145 },
 { SoC: 76, power: 115 },
 { SoC: 80, power: 80 },
 { SoC: 89, power: 60 },
 { SoC: 90, power: 55 },
 { SoC: 100, power: 0 },
];

const [chargingCurveTableData, setChargingCurveTableData] = useState(
DEFAULT_CHARGING_CURVE,
```

);

```
<TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                        <TextField
                          inputProps={{
                            'aria-label': `chargingCurveTable Row ${i}, power`,
                            style: { textAlign: 'center' },
                          }}
                          type='number'
                          value={row.power}
                          onChange={(event) => updateChargingCurveTableRowPower(
                            i,
                            event.target.value,
                          )
                          }
                        ></TextField>
                      </TableCell>
```

Answer (score 1):

add to `inputProps` step value for precision

example:

```
const TestComponent = () => {  
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  return (
      <TextField
        inputProps={{
          step: 0.1,
        }}
        variant="standard"
        label="test"
        value={value}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value)
        }}
      />
  )
}
```

I have this version "@mui/material": "^5.8.4"

Comment: No result. It still does delete the point when i try to enter a float number

Comment: @RazvanRazvi are you logging the result in onChange?  I tried it now on project and normally I have value `5.5` in state

Comment: Yes. The problem is after i enter the point to make it a floating value and enter the second number the point will dissapear

Comment: @RazvanRazvi I've updated example that works try look at it.

Comment: Thank you. Your example worked